# Use Property to get value from List<string>

Tags: c#

```
private List<string> _S3 = new List<string>();
public string S3[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return _S3[index];
    }
}
```

Only problem is I get 13 errors. I want to call `string temp = S3[0];` and get the string value from the list with the particular index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that in C# - you can't have named indexers like that in C#. You can *either* have a named property, with no parameters, *or* you can have an indexer with parameters but no name.

Of course you *can* have a property with a name which *returns* a value with an indexer. For example, for a read-only view, you could use:

```
private readonly List<string> _S3 = new List<string>();

// You'll need to initialize this in your constructor, as
// _S3View = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_S3);
private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> _S3View;

// TODO: Document that this is read-only, and the circumstances under
// which the underlying collection will change
public IList<string> S3
{
    get { return _S3View; }
}
```

That way the underlying collection is still read-only from the public point of view, but you can access an element using:

```
string name = foo.S3[10];
```

You *could* create a new `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` on each access to `S3`, but that seems a little pointless.

Answer (score 2):

C# cannot have parameters for their properties.  (Side note: VB.Net can though.)

You can try using a function instead:

```
public string GetS3Value(int index) {
  return _S3[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this notation

```
 public class Foo
    {
        public int this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return 0;
            }
            set
            {
                // use index and value to set the value somewhere.   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

_S3[i] should automatically return the string at position i

So just do:

```
string temp = _S3[0];
```

Comment: No, `_S3` is *private*. The point of creating a property is to access the values stored in `_S3` from an out of scope place.

Comment: Good point. I overlooked the private modifier in the question. 

Then you'd want to create a public method like LarsTech suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
private List<string> _S3 = new List<string>();
public List<string> S3
{
    get
    {
        return _S3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just go with

```
class S3: List<string>{}
```